# How can I efficiently design create / update methods, which need to create/update properties of different types?

Tags: c#

I know, the question is long winded and probably difficult to understand, but hopefully someone has clicked on it and I can now explain in more detail what my issue is.

I have a Create method that is used to create an object called 'opportunity'. An opportunity has many different properties that need setting, but to make it simple I will use 'Title', 'Location', and 'StartDate'.

I also have an Update method that does something very similar and with regards to the properties listed it will set them in an identical way. However, as a side note I need 2 separate methods as they do differ.

Both methods take another object called an 'Entity' as a parameter, which is used to set the values for the 'opportunity'.

So, now to my issue. I was thinking the best approach is to have 1 method that does all of the property setting, which both methods use. I would pass a list of tuples to this method that contained 1.) the opportunity property name to be set, and 2.) the entity property value to set it to. However, to do this I would presumably need a tuple like string, object as the entity property value could be 1 of 5 types. Presumably this would cause boxing (and therefore is expensive). In addition to this I would be using the type to decide how to update the given opportunity property, so something like:

```
if (PropType == typeof(string))
{
    //Do something
}
else if (PropType == typeof(Picklist))
{
    //Do something else
}
else if (PropType == typeof(DateTime))
{
    //Do something else
}
```

My question is, is this an efficient way of doing it? The 2 main reasons behind it for me are that it seems there is a lot of duplicate code between the create method and the update method as well as within each method with things like if(entity.prop.value != null) opp.prop.value = entity.prop.value. The second reason is that this way is easier to unit test. I can create a test for each opportunity property to be set and pass it into my new method as list of tuples and return if they've been created / updated correctly.

I considered a list of KeyValuePairs but I may need to add additional bits of info to the list so went with tuple. In addition, I think tuples are less expensive to pass to other methods (although more expensive to assign?).

I'm sure that despite my best efforts this still isn't clear, so any questions please ask.

***EDIT***

To give more clarity, there is an update method already in place (though I'm thinking of rewriting it) that has a lot of the same code in it to set the opportunity properties like this:

```
if(entity.Title.Value != null) opp.name = entity.Title.Value;
else throw new Exception("Title not specified");

if(entity.Town.Value != null) opp.town = entity.Town.Value;
else throw new Exception("Town not specified");
```

This is done for all string properties. My current view is I don't think I should need to duplicate this for all properties but rather have something that says:

```
//newOpp is passed in as the new opportunity

//Fields refers to a tuple passed in as object, string
//Item1 = entity field value
//Item2 = newOpp property name

PropertyInfo[] OppProps = newOpp.GetType().GetProperties();
PropertyInfo prop;

foreach (var record in Fields)
{
    prop = OppProps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == record.Item2);

    if(record.Item1 != null && prop != null)
    {
        Type PropType = prop.GetType();
        if (PropType == typeof(string))
        {
            prop.SetValue(newOpp, record.Item1, null);
        }

        //Extend to include other types used e.g. DateTime etc.
    }
}
```

Comment: will you please elaborate in SHORT ?

Comment: @SHEKHARSHETE - ok, 2 methods, very similar, don't want to duplicate code and want to be able to unit test easily. In my question are my current thoughts and issues. Is this a good way of doing it?

Comment: Why are you not passing a dto/entity/poco which contains the new values and then map them to your Opportunity object either with an automapper or manually by using a method?

Comment: @Kristof - not sure I understand your question. It seems to me that's what I'm trying to do in my method i.e. receive a list of properties to set and the values. Then try and set them.

Comment: @sr28 i'm reading things like tuples with object that can contain 5 different types so i'm kind of scared:) I made an answer (below) with some code that might clear things up. Could you tell me if the approach below is workable for you or if it's lacking a key part. As it stands it should remove to code duplicity for mapping your new data into an opportunity object

Answer (score 0):

Because code says more then a few comment lines i made an example to illustrate what i mean.

```
    public class Opportunity
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class OpportunityDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        [IgnoreMap]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
    }

    public class Saver
    {
        public void CreateOpportunity(OpportunityDto dto)
        {
            var newOpportunity = new Opportunity();//You'll need some database logic here
            MapProperties(dto, newOpportunity);
            //Add save/create logic
        }

        public void UpdateOpportunity(OpportunityDto dto)
        {
            var existingUpportunity = new Opportunity();//you'll need some database query logic here
            MapProperties(dto, existingUpportunity);
            //Add save/update logic
        }

        public void MapProperties(OpportunityDto dto, Opportunity target)
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<OpportunityDto, Opportunity>()
                  .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(srs => !srs.IsSourceValueNull));
            Mapper.Map<OpportunityDto, Opportunity>(dto, target);
            target.Startdate = dto.StartDate;//Insert more logic & mumbo jumbo here
            //Or manually :
            //target.Title = dto.Title;
            //target.Location = dto.Location;
            //target.StartDate = dto.StartDate;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is the sort of thing I thought of initially, but came up against 2 issues. 1st, this still contains a lot of code duplication as there are a lot of fields of the same type that are just set the same way e.g. if(entity.property.value != null) opp.property = entity.property.value. In your example I would need to have this type of null check for each one. In addition, some entity fields aren't always mapped to the same opportunity fields. Some logic is needed to determine which.

Comment: So if i wanted to clear the title i could only set it to an empty string but never update it to null?

Comment: @sr28 i updated my answer to include more automapper functionality. You could use an ignoreMapping for fields you want to map yourself(e.g StartDate) and by adding the condition for all members you will skip the null properties. I assume you might have more needs but automapper was made for this purpose so i hope it can fill your need.

Comment: I can see I'm going to have to look at Mapper more closely. I don't fully understand your answer at the moment. I've updated my question in the meantime to hopefully clarify my concerns over duplicate code etc.

Comment: It's called automapper, website here : http://automapper.org/. Not that you can't do it yourself with reflection but it's just a lot more hassle :)

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware you were talking about a 3rd party library. That's a no go unfortunately. To be allowed to use this would take a lot of time and red tape to get through.

Comment: Ugh, you're working at one of those companies ey :) In that case i'd still consider reworking the update/insert mechanics before building your own automapper(which kinda is what you want to do :) ). I find it kind of weird that you take an object as parameter but it has to be filled up in an exact way. If title is null then it's null and you should set it. Maybe you could try to use a sort of command pattern with constructors that take all the required fields so the calling code can't set null.

Comment: Taking your point of "If title is null then it's null and should be set", that's not quite how it works. The opportunity values need to be set, but only if the values equivalent entity values are supplied correctly. So for the Create method if entity.title.value is null, then throw an exception and don't set the opportunity.name. However, to complicate it more not all opportunity fields are mandatory, so in some cases they could be allowed to be null.